# Nested Query in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to make some nested query in InfluxDB.

I'm collecting information from many devices and saving it in the InfluxDB table. 
I'm using TAGS for identifying each device.

In SQL following Query can be used:

```
select salary from Employee where salary > (select avg(salary) from employee)
```

Can I use a similar query structure in Influx?
(In case of influx, since the information is time-series based, maybe I need to include some "group BY TIME").

Let me explain in detail:

```
SELECT meas FROM table_name WHERE meas > 15
```

Returns all measurements with a value greater than 15.

```
SELECT mean(meas) FROM table_name GROUP BY TIME (120m)
```

Returns average temperature of all devices every 2 hours.

Is there any way two combine both queries and get all measurements which are greater than the average of all measurements?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

InfluxDB should now support nested queries. You could try something like:

```
SELECT mean(meas) FROM (SELECT meas FROM table_name WHERE meas > 15) GROUP BY time(20m)
```

Comment: OP wants to "get all measurements which are greater than". Won't this query return only one value, the mean?